# Return the boolean value

Tags: java

I have to write such a program:
1.two two-dimensional arrays
 have the same dimensions m × n,
 2.satisfy the condition that aij = bij for i = 0,. . . , m and j = 0,. . . , n
The method returns the result in the form of a logical value true only when both of the above are met simultaneously.
**what does it mean "returns the result"? This means that it displays on the screen?** I wrote something like that:

```
static boolean isEqual(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    int ia = 0;`
    int ib = 0;
    int ja = 0;
    int jb = 0;
    boolean equal=true;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {

            ia++;
        }
        ja++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {

            ib++;
        }
        jb++;
    }
    if (ia == ib && ja == jb) {
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                if (a[i][j] != b[i][j]) {
                    equal= false;
                } 
            }
        }

    } else {
        equal= false;
    }
    return equal;


}
```

}

Comment: "returns the result" means that it uses a `return` statement to make the method give back a value to the calling code. You're using a `return` statement here; you're just not returning the correct value (because your calculation of `ia` and `ib` isn't correct).

Comment: how are they incorrect?

Comment: Are you intending for them to check that the arrays have the same number of rows and columns? If so, `ia` and `ib` aren't counting either of those. Try looking at their values in a debugger (or just printing them out). Incidentally, you don't need the inner loops to calculate what you're calculating here: `ib += b[i].length;` does the same, faster.

Comment: first of all ai, aj etc. it works, secondly thanks for the tip, I could do it faster. public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int[][] tab1 = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 1}};
        int[][] tab2 = {{1, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}};

        boolean res = isEqual(tab1, tab2);
        System.out.println(res);

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't need `ia`, `ib`, `ja`, and `jb`. Since you've been told that both arrays have the same dimensions (m × n), you can simply get those two values using `int m = a.length; int n = a[0].length;`

That then simplifies your code to:

```
static boolean isEqual(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    int m = a.length;
    int n = a[0].length;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if (a[i][j] != b[i][j])
                return false;
    return true;
}
```